# Loading MP3 files from mobile takes a lot time even using Async Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview, mp3

SongsManager

```
public class SongsManager {


    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(String rootPath) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> fileList = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            File rootFolder = new File(rootPath);
            File[] files = rootFolder.listFiles(); //here you will get NPE if directory doesn't contains  any file,handle it like this.
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    if (getPlayList(file.getAbsolutePath()) != null) {
                        fileList.addAll(getPlayList(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (file.getName().endsWith(".mp3")) {
                    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<>();
                    song.put("file_path", file.getAbsolutePath());
                    song.put("file_name", file.getName());
                    fileList.add(song);
                }
            }
            return fileList;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

PlaylistActivity

```
public class PlaylistActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private SongsAdapter songsAdapter;
    private SongsManager songsManager;
    String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songList=new ArrayList<>();;
    MyTask myTask;
    List<MyTask> myTasks;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_playlist);
        myTasks=new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.playlistactivityrecyclerview);
        progressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        myTask=new MyTask();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
            } else {
                myTask.execute();
            }

        }

    }

    public void updateRecycler(){

        songsAdapter=new SongsAdapter(songList,getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(songsAdapter);
    }

    public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void,String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            if(myTasks.size()==0){
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            myTasks.add(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            songsManager=new SongsManager();
            songList =songsManager.getPlayList(MEDIA_PATH);
            return songList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> hashMaps) {
            super.onPostExecute(hashMaps);
            myTasks.remove(this);
            if(myTasks.size()==0){
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            if(hashMaps==null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No mp3 Files",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            updateRecycler();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(requestCode==0){
            if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                myTask.execute();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am loading all my mp3 files in recyclerview with a textview in it.The loading of mp3 files takes a lot of time.Even when I use AsyncTask it takes a lot of time.Please help me with what am I doing wrong? I tried doing it without asynctask, then too it takes a lot of time.Is there any more efficient way to retrieve mp3 files?

Comment: "Please help me with what am I doing wrong?" -- you are not querying the `MediaStore` for all indexed MP3 content.

Answer (score 0):

Using `AsyncTask` doesn't necessarily reduce the time taken to do some operation. It just does the same work in a background thread, so that the UI thread does not get blocked and the UI is responsive for the user interactions.

So there won't be any difference in the time taken if you use `AsyncTask` or not. The only thing you have to see is whether the UI doesn't get blocked and is responsive to the user interactions.

Comment: So do you know how to retrieve mp3 files fast?